# class vs functions oop

Tags: php, oop

i am a newbie to oops..

i was going through this book [Php 5 social networking](http://www.amazon.in/PHP-5-Social-Networking-ebook/dp/B0057G9RQK/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1371891460&sr=1-1&keywords=php+5+social+networking) and this book has given a step by step explanation for 
creating a social networking site from scratch using oops.

The first step as given in the book is to create a bunch of core classes for the tasks given below:

- Database access
- Template management
- Authentication
- Email Sending
- Url processing

Then they have used a Registry class to wrap these objects.

This is the code for the Database access class:

```
/**
 * Database management / access class: basic abstraction
 *
 * @author Michael Peacock
 * @version 1.0
 *         
 */
class Mysqldb {
    /**
     * Allows multiple database connections
     * each connection is stored as an element in the array, and the
     * active connection is maintained in a variable (see below)
     */
    private $connections = array();
    /**
     * Tells the DB object which connection to use
     * setActiveConnection($id) allows us to change this
     */
    private $activeConnection = 0;
    /**
     * Queries which have been executed and the results cached for
     * later, primarily for use within the template engine
     */
    private $queryCache = array();
    /**
     * Data which has been prepared and then cached for later usage,
     * primarily within the template engine
     */
    private $dataCache = array();
    /**
     * Number of queries made during execution process
     */
    private $queryCounter = 0;

    /**
     * Record of the last query
     */
    private $last;
    /**
     * Reference to the registry object
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * Construct our database object
     */
    public function __construct(Registry $registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new database connection
     * @param String database hostname
     * @param String database username
     * @param String database password
     * @param String database we are using
     * @return int the id of the new connection
     *        
     */
    public function newConnection($host, $user, $password, $database) {
        $this->connections[] = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
        $connection_id = count($this->connections) - 1;
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            trigger_error('Error connecting to host. ' . $this->connections[$connection_id]->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $connection_id;
    }

    /**
     * Change which database connection is actively used for the next
     * operation
     * @param int the new connection id
     * @return void
     *
     */
    public function setActiveConnection(int $new) {
        $this->activeConnection = $new;
    }

    /**
     * Execute a query string
     * @param String the query
     * @return void
     *
     */
    public function executeQuery($queryStr) {
        if (! $result = $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->query($queryStr)) 

        {
            trigger_error('Error executing query: ' . $queryStr . ' -
' . $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        } else 

        {
            $this->last = $result;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the rows from the most recently executed query, excluding
     * cached queries
     * @return array
     *
     */
    public function getRows() {
        return $this->last->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Delete records from the database
     * @param String the table to remove rows from
     * @param String the condition for which rows are to be removed
     * @param int the number of rows to be removed
     * @return void
     *
     */
    public function deleteRecords($table, $condition, $limit) {
        $limit = ($limit == '') ? '' : ' LIMIT ' . $limit;
        $delete = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE {$condition} {$limit}";
        $this->executeQuery($delete);
    }

    /**
     * Update records in the database
     * @param String the table
     * @param array of changes field => value
     * @param String the condition
     * @return bool
     *
     */
    public function updateRecords($table, $changes, $condition) {
        $update = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET ";
        foreach($changes as $field => $value) {
            $update .= "`" . $field . "`='{$value}',";
        }
        // remove our trailing ,
        $update = substr($update, 0, - 1);
        if ($condition != '') {
            $update .= "WHERE " . $condition;
        }
        $this->executeQuery($update);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Insert records into the database
     * @param String the database table
     * @param array data to insert field => value
     * @return bool
     *
     */
    public function insertRecords($table, $data) {
        // setup some variables for fields and values
        $fields = "";
        $values = "";
        // populate them
        foreach($data as $f => $v) {
            $fields .= "`$f`,";
            $values .= (is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) ? $v . "," : "'$v',";
        }
        // remove our trailing ,
        $fields = substr($fields, 0, - 1);
        // remove our trailing ,
        $values = substr($values, 0, - 1);
        $insert = "INSERT INTO $table ({$fields}) VALUES({$values})";
        // echo $insert;
        $this->executeQuery($insert);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize data
     * @param String the data to be sanitized
     * @return String the sanitized data
     *        
     */
    public function sanitizeData($value) {
        // Stripslashes
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        // Quote value
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), "4.3.0") == "-1") {
            $value = $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->escape_string($value);
        } else {
            $value = $this->connections[$this->activeConnection]->real_escape_string($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the rows from the most recently executed query, excluding
     * cached queries
     * @return array
     *
     */
    public function getRows() {
        return $this->last->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    public function numRows() {
        return $this->last->num_rows;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of affected rows from the previous query
     * @return int the number of affected rows
     *        
     */
    public function affectedRows() {
        return $this->last->affected_rows;
    }

    /**
     * Deconstruct the object
     * close all of the database connections
     */
    public function __deconstruct() {
        foreach($this->connections as $connection) {
            $connection->close();
        }
    }
}
```

The main objective of using oops as i understand is to allow the application to evolve gracefully 
to the changing requirements (source : [Design Patterns explained a new persective](http://www.amazon.in/Design-Patterns-Explained-Perspective-Object-Oriented/dp/0201715945/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1371891557&sr=1-2&keywords=design+patterns+a+new+perspective)) and they have given some nice examples
in this book to explain this.

So my question is what possible change in requirements in the application would warrant the use of a class for database
management in this case instead of lets say using a bunch of functions to get the job done?

I have seen the same thing in `codeigniter` where the database class resides in the `DB_driver.php` and `DB_active_rec.php.`
What difference will it make if they were to put these db functions in a helper file instead of a putting it in a library?

I have already gone through the answers given in this forum but none of them answers 
this question from a requirements point of view

Thanks..

Comment: Just try to implement it using functions and compare.

Answer (score 2):

Putting logic inside classes is primarily for ease of organization but there are some advantages when it comes to how data is shared among the common context. you can create a physical separation of the code when you encapsulate them in to different classes like `db`, `template` unlike having them in multiple files which contains just functions. classes allow to group functions together and set scope for data sharing.

if you need any examples let me know. but you seem to know what your talking about.

Based on your comment below i thought of some more things i can add to this post.

When you start to think `OO` there will be a paradigm shift in your thinking. It has to happen on your brain before it all starts making sense. If you continue to think procedural like i need to do this so i need a function. Think like i need to do this, why? what is it? and then construct an object with it and think what else i can do with it? How can i organize it well so i can also share it with someone else. `If when i do other things with it if there is a common resource i need to access how do i keep reference to it.`

Comment: As far as the ease of organization is concerned, codeigniter for instance seems to have a lot of helper files which contains just functions and the whole architecture still looks pretty clean...as for "setting scope for data sharing" i assume that you are talking abt the disadvt of global data but is that reason enough to create a seperate classes ..dont you think it is an overkill?

Comment: setting the datascope is a big requirement. personally i don't think its overkill. depends on where you are coming from.

Comment: i add some more comment for you